# Error en migración de v8 a v16 con la función array_append

Tags: postgresql

Estamos migrando la estructura de una base de datos postgresql de versión 8.4.22 a versión 16.1 bajo sistema operativo Red Hat 8.5.0-15.
Hemos creado en v16 la base de datos con la misma definición que en origen:

```
CREATE DATABASE fioteca_sicho 
   WITH OWNER = dbadmin
   ENCODING = 'LATIN9'
   TABLESPACE = ts_fioteca_sicho
   LC_COLLATE = 'es_ES@euro'
   LC_CTYPE = 'es_ES@euro'
   TEMPLATE=template0
   CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Los comandos que hemos utilizado para el export/import son:

1. Export en v8:

`pg_dump --schema-only --format plain fioteca_sicho > estructura_fioteca_sicho.sql`

2. Import en v16:

`psql -d fioteca_sicho -a -f estructura_fioteca_sicho.sql > estructura_fioteca_sicho.log 2> estructura_fioteca_sicho.err`

Se han producido los siguientes dos errores:

> psql:estructura_fioteca_sicho.sql:178957: ERROR:  no existe la función array_append(anyarray, anyelement)
> psql:estructura_fioteca_sicho.sql:178959: ERROR:  no existe la función de agregación public.util_array_agg(anyelement)

El código que parece que está fallando es el siguiente:

```
  CREATE AGGREGATE util_array_agg(anyelement) (
        SFUNC = array_append,
        STYPE = anyarray,
        INITCOND = '{}'
    );
```

Hemos visto algún problema relacionado pero no una solución concreta para este error.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hay que mirar las notas de versión... Desde PostgreSQL 14 hubo un gran cambio (buscá `array_append()` en las [notas de versión de PostgreSQL 14](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/release-14.html#id-1.11.6.6.4)). Y prestá mucha atención a la oración siguiente donde se menciona a esa función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era un problema de cambio de tipos en la versión 16.1 que, como indicas, viene de la versión 14.
Finalmente funcionó la siguiente solución:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE util_array_agg(anycompatible) (
       SFUNC = array_append,
       STYPE = anycompatiblearray,
       INITCOND = '{}'
   );
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta. Además, como los comentarios son efímeros, es mejor que coloques el enlace de referencia a la documentación para que la respuesta no quede sin mayor contexto.